# how to send connection refused to websocket client using faye-websocket-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faye

Im trying to set up a websocket connection to a rails server using the faye-websocket-ruby gem 
Ive succesfully stablished the connection basing my code largely on this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets

(Here is the code on github: https://github.com/heroku-examples/ruby-websockets-chat-demo)

The thing is, after the check

```
if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
```

passes, i want to be able to return a connection refused error to the websocket client if a condition isnt met. How would I go about this? Is there any method in the Faye::Websocket api to return an error? (Which I havent found)
Maybe I just need to send back a connection refused error using rails? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was rather easy.
The way to return a response in rack is just:

```
return [401, {}, ["CONNECTION REFUSED"]]
```